# does padding a file change its content?

Tags: padding

i'm working on implementing an algorithm which split a file to shares and i have the number of shares. in case the file size has a remainder (after modulus with the number of shares)  i'm padding it with zeros. for now, i am trying to do this with strings and when i need to recombine them i get in addition of the the extra padding. is it the same with files? or maybe the padding zeros won't change the file content?

and if it does change, is there any way of knowing which zeros are the padding zeros?

thanx!

Comment: zeros are content, just like ones, twos, threes etc. Adding zeros to a file is going to change its content.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, adding anything to a file changes its contents. In some cases this may not matter much, but for a general purpose solution you should never rely on that.

In your particular case padding the file is a bad idea.

If you had a fixed block size that every file part must fit in, it would be possible to pad a file part with bytes that indicate how many bytes have been added. For example, if you added seven bytes as padding, every padding byte should be 0x07. When you later recombine the parts, your program would first have to strip off the padding. In the given example it would read the last byte of the part, i.e. 0x07, and conclude that seven bytes have to be removed from the end of the file.

There are two problems with this approach:

- the maximum padding you can achieve is 0xff = 255 bytes
- if no padding is required you'd have to add a full block of dummy padding, because your program cannot distinguish between a padding byte and original content. If the file part ended on 0x01 and no padding was required, your combine program would remove the last byte from the segment, thereby corrupting the file.

If you are doing this just for fun you could have a look at the source code of the `split` program that you can find on BSD or GNU/Linux. Hint: no padding is required.